# How do I call .lower on a class object?

Tags: python, class

I have a class I've called Earthquake, and it has a location as a string, and a few other parts that aren't important to this question (I don't think). 
I've written a function (filter_by_place) that iterates through a list of Earthquakes that I've passed it, and looks for a given word in each Earthquake location string. If the word is found in the Earthquake's location, then it adds that Earthquake to a list. My problem is that it cannot be case sensitive, and I'm trying to make it that way by looking for an all lowercase word in an all lowercase version of the location string.

```
def filter_by_place(quakes, word):
   lst = []
   for quake in quakes:
      if word.lower in (quake.place).lower:
      lst.append(quake)
   return lst
```

I get an error saying "TypeError: argument of type 'builtin_function_or_method' is not itterable"
So, my question is: How do I get that string within the class to become lowercase just for this function so I can search for the word without worrying about case sensitivity?

I've already tried adding

```
if word.lower or word.upper in quake.place:
```

inside the for loop, but that didn't work, and I can understand why. Help?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error because you're not actually calling the `lower` string function. I am guessing you're coming from ruby where this wouldn't be required.

Try:

```
def filter_by_place(quakes, word):
   lst = []
   for quake in quakes:
      if word.lower() in quake.place.lower():
         lst.append(quake)
   return lst
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `word.lower()`. You're missing the brackets. Happens all the time :)

Try this

```
def filter_by_place(quakes, word):
    lst = []
    for quake in quakes:
        if word.lower() in quake.place.lower():
            lst.append(quake)
    return lst
```

Because you're using python, you might want to take a look at [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). You're code would then look something like this

```
def filter_by_place(quakes, place):
    return [quake for quake in quakes if quakes.place.lower() is place]
```

Comment: Thank you! That is a much more graceful way of doing it. I appreciate the help :)